# newcommand latex arguments

Tags: latex, biblatex

just a quick question, I could not find an answer to on Google.

I need to introduce a secondary citation method for my LaTeX project. And I cannot get it to work.

```
\newcommand{\sekcite[4]}{
    {
        (\cite[#1]{#2} qtd. in \cite[#4]{#3})
    }
}
```

I have  in my text the following lines for testing purposes:

```
\par \textcite[1]{Su2016}
\par \parencite[2]{Spar2014}
\par \sekcite{Su2016}{1}{Spar2014}{2}
```

The desired outcome should look like this:

> C. H. Su, Fan, and P. Y. Su (2016, p. 1)
>
> (Sparwelt.de 2014, p. 2)
>
> (C. H. Su, Fan, and P. Y. Su 2016, p. 1 qtd. in Sparwelt.de 2014, p. 2)

The problem is, that I get:

> C. H. Su, Fan, and P. Y. Su (2016, p. 1)
>
> (Sparwelt.de 2014, p. 2)
>
> (C. H. Su, Fan, and P. Y. Su 2016, p. 0 qtd. in **1**) 2

As I read here: http://www.golatex.de/wiki/%5Cnewcommand

I can create a new command with

```
\newcommand{\NAME}[COUNT]{CODE}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: What I should have added: I get following warning:

> The following entry could not be found(biblatex) in the database:(biblatex) 1(biblatex) Please verify the spelling and rerun(biblatex) LaTeX afterwards.

And I am using Texmaker 4.5 on MiKTeX in the current stable version on Windows 7

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal example that replicates your behaviour? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
\newcommand{\sekcite}[4]{%
  (\cite[#2]{#1} qtd.\ in \cite[#4]{#3})%
}
```

[Note the use of `%`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764). Additionally, the use of `\`  after the `.` ensures you don't have a sentence-ending period space.

Comment: It worked, i have spotted that the major mistake was that i placed the [4] wrong. Yor additional information helped me as well (even though mostly in different circumstances).